# Custom ensemble scikit-learn model NotFittedError after fitting models with multiprocessing

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, multiprocessing

I am trying to make an ensemble model and train using the multiprocessing module. Can someone explain why this produces a "NotFittedError"? Here is a reproducible example I made to demonstrate what happens:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

X = [np.random.normal(size=10) for _ in range(10)]
Y = [np.random.choice([0,1]) for _ in range(10)]

class ensemble(object):
    def __init__(self, num_models):
        self._models = [RandomForestClassifier() for _ in range(num_models)]

    def train(self, training_data, training_labels):
        _fit = lambda model, data, labels: model.fit(data, labels)
        processes = [mp.Process(target=_fit, args=(self._models[index],
                                                   training_data,
                                                   training_labels)) for index in range(len(self._models))]
        [p.start() for p in processes]
        [p.join() for p in processes]

        # try to predict with one of the models in the ensemble
        self._models[0].predict(training_data)

e = ensemble(num_models=2)
e.train(X, Y)
```